# What would you recommand for team messaging / video conferencing, etc

Tags: chat, video-conferencing, screen-sharing

It seems like everybody wants to become/beat Slack : Amazon Chime, Cisco Spark, Microsoft Team, etc.

I'm in a situation where my needs are pretty straightforward, but where the solution is not that obvious.

Ours needs (very simple) :

- Be able to chat (one on one and in groups)
- Be able to make video call (actually using Skype -not for business- and video calls with more than 2 participants are painful)
- Be able to share screens during a meeting (with or without videos)

We are using JIRA and Confluence also.

What would you recommand?

Comment: Self-hosted or hosted? Is installation of clients okay (if yes, which operating systems need to be supported?), or does it have to be a web app?

Comment: I would prefer hosted, but self-hosted could be an option too. It must support Windows, MAC, Androis and iOS. A web app is optional.